# How to reverse compile a linux library?

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, compiler-optimization, nm

I want to figure out what files are used to create a library. Is there a simple way to find this?

(Without using reverse engineering tools like Ida etc..)
I suspect it might be possible with some tool similar to nm. I didn't see any possibility by looking at man page of nm.

I have a static library from a large code compiled with intel without documentation and I need to recompile the file without breaking anyting using gcc. But I don't know how the library was created.

Comment: You can't recover the source code of the source files from which a static library was
built. You can recover a disassembly of each of the object files it contains.

Comment: Found this command gives the object files:               ar t libsimint.a | pr -4 -t